# Ordering from largest to smallest in relational algebra

Tags: database, relational-algebra

I am tasked with ordering a group of objects in a database from largest(in inches) to smallest. How can I express this in relational algebra? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not with the classical relational algebra described by Codd. You see, relational algebra is dealing with sets of tuples, and sets are by definition unordered. The `order by` clause we know from SQL is dealing with the *display* of the data set, in which context ordering is meaningful.

Of course, we can easily extend relational algebra with a function that transforms a relation into an ordered data structure, but note that this operation is not closed, so it kind of breaks the algebra. For such practical extensions of relational algebra see for example [these lecture notes.](https://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~jdonalds/311/lecture12.html)