# How to get ORDER BY clause representation in Relational Algebra?

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

I want to get account related information by using Relational Algebra based on the descending order of the `balance` attribute.

Table:
`Account (id, account_number, branch_name, balance)`

How to get ORDER BY clause representation in Relational Algebra?

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. PS "related information" & based on" don't mean anything in particular. Neither sorting nor aggregation are needed to find the MIN or MAX of an attribute in a relation via a relational algebra. (How to do it is a faq.) But you don't actually clearly say what you are trying to do that led to the question you actually asked. [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/266284) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & sometimes limited to titles, but read the help. Google re googling/searching, including in Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: [Algebra Relational sql GROUP BY SORT BY ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28665635/3404097) [Ordering from largest to smallest in relational algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26283943/3404097) [Aggregate Relational Algebra (Maximum)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4952451/3404097) 
[How can I find MAX with relational algebra?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5493691/3404097) 
[Query using aggregation and/or groups in relational algebra - count, max, min, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15660545/3404097)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible; relational algebra is about sets, which don't have an order. In [this book on SQL and relation theory](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/sql-and-relational/9781449319724/ch07s13.html) it is stated that "ORDER BY isn’t actually part of the relational algebra". Also, [there's a quite thorough answer to a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28668963/10974490).

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please put what is needed to answer in your post, not just at a link. Paraphrase or quote from other text with credit. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem.